# Getting postgresql connection object back from the string

Tags: python, database, string, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I am using a PostgreSQL connection from Google cloud platform. I am writing a pub/sub function that makes the PostgreSQL connection and does the task. Since the GCP provides only 25 connections at max, whenever the requests are too large in number like around 20,000, it fails. So I came with an idea to send the connection object over the post API call. But I cannot send the connection object directly. So I converted it to the string. But now I want to convert it back to the Connection object.
How do I do that?

```
string_conn=str(conn)
json_data={
    'con':string_conn
}

response=requests.post(url,json=json_data)
print(response.status_code)
```

This is the code to convert from <class 'psycopg2.extensions.connection'> object to string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share connections like that between different processes.

You also can't convert objects to string representation and share them like that, what you would use for such a thing is pickle: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html or for simpler objects you could use a text serialization format such as json.

It sounds to me like your options are:

- Use a db with more memory, which allows for more connections
- Limit your number of parallel functions to 25
- Use a different type of database that is more suitable for your needs